# 'NSError' is not convertible to 'UInt8'

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

Although i have looked through the other "not convertible to UInt8" answers, I have not found one that I understand.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

the below code is throwing the error - 'NSError' is not convertible to 'UInt8'

```
if( error != nil) {...}
```

Can anyone explain why checking if the error is nil would throw this "error" haha.

I can get the error to go away by making the nil option and changing the code to

```
if( error != nil!) {...}
```

Am I doing that correctly? Should i be doing something else instead?

Comment: file a bug, that the swift interpreter gives crappy non-helpful errors... that is what I would do if I wasn't so discouraged by the crappy, misleading, not helpful errors.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps that error message isn't as useful as it should be, but the compiler is correct for complaining here. Notice that in the error you're receiving that the `NSError` type that it's complaining about is `NSError`, not `NSError?` or `NSError!`.

This means that your `error` variable is of the non-optional `NSError` type and therefore can never be nil, and making the nil check unnecessary. I think you will find that if you redeclare your error object as either an optional, or an implicitly unwrapped optional, your code will work just fine.